# backbone.js update a collection with jsonp

Tags: backbone.js, jsonp

When I first initialized a collection, I use

```
this.fooCollection = new myCollection();
this.fooCollection.fetch({dataType: 'jsonp'});
```

This works fine.
But when I try to update this collection later in a view, using

```
this.fooCollection.fetch({dataType: 'jsonp'});
```

it doesn't update the collection at all. It doesn't call the 'success' callback either. From Firebug, I can find the response is as expected, but in the NET panel of Firebug, I can't find the JSON tab. Anybody knows what's the right way to update an existing collection using jsonp?

Comment: update: ended up with adding CORS support to my django backend, so no JSONP is needed. It just makes GET/POST work the same as a same-site request. Here is the middleware I used: https://gist.github.com/1369619